# Localhost taking too long. What to do?

Tags: php, windows, windows-8, localhost, response

I'm working on a project. Yesterday it was working very fine but when I've updated my system OS from Windows 7 32 bit to Windows 8 64 bit and wamp server from 32 bit to 64 bit now I'm getting very slow localhost response in my Php project (6 Senonds delay on each page) also I didn't change anything within the script. Unable to identify what could be the problem.

Comment: You should tag "windows", "Windows 8" etc also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just changed the server name from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in database connection configuration and it worked light speed.

Comment: Where should i look for the constant.php file ?

Comment: Same question here. Where is that constant.php?

Comment: Changing the MySQL host from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` has improved things, but still every few minutes, I have to wait 10-15 seconds for it to connect to the database. Incredibly frustrating

Comment: Still One of the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

[**WAMPServer**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) has some probelms with Windows 8. Use [**XAMPP**](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). I am a hardcore WAMPServer user. But, had to switch to XAMPP due to some threading issues.

You can read more about the issue [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,91274).

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the ipv6 also improves response speed issue.

http://www.techunboxed.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-8.html

Comment: This helped me when trying to make my webserver accessible from the internet on Windows 8.1! It wouldn't work, not matter what I tried. It kept saying "Server not found" or "Timeout" all the time.
Disabling IPv6 solved all my problems - both WAMP and XAMPP websites can not be accessed from the web! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

As an IPV6 issue, here is how you make MYSQL not to use it. (so, without disabling IPV6)

edit mysql file 'my.ini'

under the [wampmysqld] add the following:
bind-address = ::

save file and restart mysql service

enjoy!

Comment: Completely life saving! The time taken to complete a request went from 4 seconds to instantaneous!

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my fix with this similar problem.

Try changing the permission of the user "Authenticated Users" of the drive where XAMPP is installed (for me its C:). Right click Drive C:\, click "Security" tab, edit "Authenticated Users", allow everything except "full control" and "special permission" which you can't. Apply and OK. Restart XAMPP.